# Telethon Python channel statement

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I'm trying to create a user bot that will forward a message from specific channel to a group. I succesfully managed forwarding all messages to the certain group (but that's quite annoying) and want to create statement when on specific group message will be received, then forward it to the group.

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='channelID'))
   async def forward(event):
      await event.forward_to(-groupID)
```

However the pattern "statement" will only check words that are sent to me. Is there possibility to create statement for channel ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(channelID))
   async def forward(event):
      await event.forward_to(destinationGroupID)
```

Solution here.